# Asp.net Core and Microsoft account authentication access denied

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to setup Microsoft Account Authentication in an ASP.net core application.
I pretty much followed [ben day's post](http://www.benday.com/2016/05/14/walkthrough-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/) expect I couldn't get to the end.
Once the user is redirect to the step where it should enter the email address, I'm instead redirected to an access denied page (from my asp.net application).
In the console I can see the following error messsages:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 1260.8977ms 302 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44394/
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: .
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Warning: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External was successfully authenticated.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External was forbidden.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Microsoft was forbidden.

Here is my current configuration (very simple)

> app.UseIdentity();
>               app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions
>               {
>                   DisplayName = "Microsoft Account",
>                   ClientId = "my id",
>                   ClientSecret = "my secret",
>                   AutomaticChallenge = true
>               });

Any idea why I get an access denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to build a Asp.Net core web application which authenticate with the Microsoft Account and it works well for me. It using the cookie and Microsoft Account components and here is the code for your reference:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions {
            DisplayName = "Microsoft Account",
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = "",
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            SignInScheme= "Cookies"
});

public async Task Login()
{

     await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
}
```

And you can refer the full code samples from [here](https://github.com/VitorX/ASPCore_MicrosoftAccount). To run this code sample, you need to register the apps from [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F) first and add the web platform and config the redirect URL http://localhost:7507/signin-microsoft.

And for the original issue, since there is no Asp.net 5 templates anymore, it is helpful if you can provide a demo project to help to reproduce this issue.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm, I had tried with cookie auth too but with more options, and I didn't have the account controller. So I guess one or the other was the one missing.

Comment: This is not working anymore. I tried following the latest .NET 7 and it simply throws a long  list of exceptions like this. Any idea? (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<AuthenticateAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<AuthenticateAsync>d__14, Microsoft.AspNetCore.)